# What is this MySQL query actually means?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Someone suggested me an query he made in order to get summary of time elapsed since start to end
but it seems like i cannot really understand its query :

```
SELECT w.*,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ws.start, ws.end)) summary
FROM workers w LEFT JOIN
     work_sessions ws
     ON w.id = ws.worker_id
GROUP BY w.id
```

Please help

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the person who made the suggestion.  What part of the query do you not understand?  It seems rather clear.

Comment: Im new to MySQL and clearly dont really know what this query actually do in one line

Comment: I do see 6 lines, which of the 6 lines do you not understand? (Try to make your problem more clear than just "I am new to (My)SQL" )

Comment: SELECT w.*, 
HOUR inside parenthasis is it an alias?

Comment: *i cannot really understand its query* This query calculates the difference between `ws.start` and `ws.end` in full hours (i.e. ceiling the difference), then summarizes the differences per user. PS. `id` must be primary key in `workers`, if not then the query is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT w.*,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ws.start, ws.end)) summary
FROM workers w LEFT JOIN
     work_sessions ws
     ON w.id = ws.worker_id
GROUP BY w.id
```

`SELECT w.*` will seelct all field from the table with the name (or alias) `w`

`SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ws.start, ws.end)) summary`  will output the value from the function, using [SUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) and [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), and give this column the aias `summary`

.... etc.